# Sprite Kit SKAction Group Halting Application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, sprite-kit

I am trying to override the removeFromParent action in my sprite so that when a sprite is removed, it "explodes" first, however, when I run the SKAction group action, the application freezes and quits.

The problematic code is as follows:

```
class Trampoline: SKSpriteNode {
     override func removeFromParent() {
        //remove the physics body. The trampoline is essentially gone
        self.physicsBody = nil

        //create an array of explosion images from to animate
        var explosionAtlas: SKTextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "explosion")
        var explosionFrames: [SKTexture] = [SKTexture]()
        var numImages: Int = explosionAtlas.textureNames.count
        var i = 1
        for (i = 1; i <= numImages; i++) {
            explosionFrames.append(explosionAtlas.textureNamed("explosion-\(i)"))
        }

        //execute the explodion and then deletion of the node
        let explosionAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(explosionFrames, timePerFrame: 0.03, resize: true, restore: true)
        let removeAction = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        let group = SKAction.group([explosionAction, removeAction])
        self.runAction(group)
    }
}
```

When I run ONLY the explosion action, things work fine (so it's not an issue with my texture atlas). The explosion displays and animates. However, even if I run only the removeAction, the application freezes. Running them as a group freezes immediately (even before the explosion animation occurs).

Am I using the API wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

Your problem is you're creating an infinite loop.

You're overriding `removeFromParent` and then inside `removeFromParent` you're calling `removeFromParent` with `SKAction.removeFromParent()`.

You can observe the infinite loop yourself by adding `println` or a breakpoint in your `removeFromParent` and see how many times it's being called. You can also see the infinite loop if you wait for Xcode to kill your app and have a look at the call stack - it should be full of `removeFromParent`.

**The Solution**

You should change your removeAction to:

```
let removeAction = SKAction.runBlock { super.removeFromParent() }
```

This change means you're letting `SKSpriteNode` (`Trampoline`'s `super` class) handle the actual removal.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! That makes complete sense! I actually wasn't even aware of the runBlock api.

Answer (score 0):

This only a guess. I have a hint for you:

```
    yourSprite.removeFromParent()
```

And in your code you are using:

```
    SKAction.removeFromParent()
```

I think you are saying your "self" to remove instead of your node:

yourNode.runAction(group)

Edited